# Django returning 500 status code instead of 404 for a not found resources

Tags: python, django

In my Django project whenever I turn DEBUG to False all my 404 resource not found errors, returns as 500 internal server error. I also don't get a stack trace in my log file for the cause of the error. I just only get internal server error with status code 500.
But if DEBUG is set to true, it works fine and I get a 404 not found code for a resource not found error

Even some of my static files and images that were not found are all returning 500 internal server error. This happens only when debug is false

Works fine when debug is set to true.

I read online where allowed host must be set to the actual host and not a "*". I have done all this but it is still not working.

I am still getting 500 status code for a resource not found error and no stack trace.

I'm using Django 4 python 3.9

Comment: How do you run your app? It should show you logs for every request if you run it properly.